# Mouse and keyboard don't work when used at the same time

Tags: debian, i3, laptop

I am running the i3 window manager with Debian 9 Stretch on a laptop with a trackpad.

I have run into the problem that whenever I type, the mouse is disabled. Is this normal behavior or a bug?

nonfree repos have been enabled and linux-firmware-nonfree has been installed. The bug does not show up on other distributions.

This does not happen with a USB mouse

xinput output

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
HP TrueVision HD                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
HP Wireless hotkeys                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
HP WMI hotkeys                              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Touchpad Properties

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (277): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (278): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (279):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (280):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (281):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (283):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (284):  1, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (285): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (286): 0.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (287):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (288):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (289): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (290): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (294):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (295):    1
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event1"
    Device Product ID (266):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (296):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (297):   1
```

Comment: Some touchpads have a feature that disable touch events during typing, to avoid interpreting accidental touches. As you provide no information about your trackpad, I can't say if your trackpad has this feature. `xinput` can be used to list and set properties of input devices.

Comment: I have edited my post to show the output of xinput

Comment: Now read `man xinput`, and list the *properties* of the Elantech Touchpad.

Comment: I've listed the touchpad properties, then I tried the command xinput --set-int-prop "ETPS/T Elantech Touchpad 294 0 but I got the output "Invalid format 0"

Comment: I also tried using the actual name of the property instead of "294"

Comment: The man page says about `--set-int-prop`: "Deprecated,  use  `--set-prop` instead". You can use the numerical ids (in parenthesis) instead of strings for both device and property, and if you want to use strings, you'll have to quote device and property separately (`xinput --set-prop "some device" "some property" "some value"`). Once it works, write up an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem I was having involved the *Disable While Typing Enabled* feature of my trackpad. These are the steps I used to solve it.

1. Make sure `xinput` is installed.
2. Type `xinput` to find the name of the trackpad device. Mine was `ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad`.
3. Run `xinput --list-props "DEVICE"` to list the properties of the device.
4. Go through the list until you find something like `Disable While Typing`.
5. Use

   ```
   xinput --set-prop "DEVICE" ID_OF_PROPERTY 0
   ```

   For me, this was

   ```
   xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" 294 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For me, with XFCE on Debian 11 only the following worked:

1. Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`
2. Comment out `Option "SendEventsMode" "disabled-on-external-mouse"` under inputclass with identifier `libinput touchpad catchall`

Mine looked like this in end:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "TappingDrag" "True"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
    Option "AccelProfile" "adaptive"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "0.4"
    #Option "SendEventsMode" "disabled-on-external-mouse"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

Note: I had also to restart X11 for this to take effect.